# Nesting URLSession.shared.dataTask in Swift 4

Tags: nested, swift4, completionhandler, urlsession

I am trying to fetch data from an api where the JSON returned has URLs to other pieces of information that I need, such as

```
"value1" : "data",
"value2": {
    "url": "https://example.com/stuff",
    }
```

My logic is as follows:

```
func(completion: @escaping ([Data]) -> ()) {
       var classArray = [myClass]()
       URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
                
       guard let data = data else { return }

       do {

           guard let resultArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any] else { return }

           let myObject = myClass(value1: resultArray["value1"]! as! String)

           guard let valueUrl = URL(string: resultArray["value2"]! as! String) else { return }

           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: valueUrl) { (data, _, _) in
                
                myObject.value2 = data
                classArray.append(myObject)

           }.resume()

           } catch let error {
               print("Failed to create json with error: ", error.localizedDescription)
           }
           completion(classArray)
      }.resume()
   }
}
```

Is this a valid approach or are there better implementations? Trying to avoid a future Pyramid of Doom situation. I have tried putting the inner URLSession call in a separate private function but still receive an empty classArray in the end.

Comment: First of all the name `resultArray` is misleading because it's actually a dictionary. Second of all the `completion` parameter type doesn't match the type in the `completion` call. Third of all never ignore errors in asynchronous tasks, handle them. – Move the line `completion(classArray)` into the completion handler of the inner data task (right after `classArray.append(myObject)`)

Comment: I’d also suggest getting rid of all of those forced unwrapping operators (`!`), too. But moving the `completion` closure inside the second `dataTask` will solve your “empty” result problem.

Comment: It’s hard for us to answer the question of how to get an array of `Data` when you provided JSON that only has one URL in it. Also, how many URLs might you be dealing with? If it’s always only two or three, that suggests one approach. But if it could be really large number of URLs, that would call for another approach.